# error message when starting rails console in with environment as production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

I am running the command "rails s -e=production" and get the following error:

`` connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified) ``

Contents of my config/database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: ***.***.***.***
  database: gmi_******
  username: **
  password: **

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: ***.***.***.***
  database: gmi_******
  username: **
  password: **
```

I have looked at all the other questions on this and the one issue was that he did not have a space between adapter like this "adapter:sqlserver" and the other one he had custom names for the servers like "Listing_production" but didn't account for it. This works fine in development but wont work in production. Please help!

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `-e=` is confusing Rails. Try this instead: `rails s -e production`

Comment: Wow. I totally feel stupid now. I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me. (In 5 minutes)